# Dynamic control in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

[image]

I am generating Checkbox & Radio button within `ng-repeat` when my page is creating new record each time the control name gets duplicate causing issue in validation.

How can I change/create name dynamically?

*Note*: `$index` is not working when I join it with control name. As `$index` restart for new item. Refer screen attached

Comment: Add logical code you did

Comment: Post  your code here, so that we can have a quick look. But if I am getting your question right then  "ng-form" is what you need.